# How to make a dynamic room for multiplayer quiz app using firebase?

Tags: firebase, multiplayer

I am making an app.. I mean a game type app. it's a quiz app where two people can
pair them up and can answer questions one by one and so on.
what I want is:
I want to make a virtual room,
when USER1 want to play he will click search competitor, a virtual room with random string key will be made with one player.
then when USER2 will click on find competitor button his room will also be created and he will also search all rooms created before him, if any room have less than 2 users then he will join that room and start playing.
I am new so I am not sure if that is good approach but that's all I have planned.
how to count childs of a node (node that we does not know whats its key..
)
see attached image

[please find image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vuVv.png)

Answer (score 1):

Good start. It's always best to articulate precisely what you want before your start coding. It sounds like you have a pretty good idea of what you want.

I would recommend using Firestore and `firebase.auth`, even if only anonymous, so that each user can have 'state' and univeral id in their app. In other words when they close and re-open the app, the app keeps a universal id, uid, for them.

If I understand your requirements:

- each user can have more than one room
- each room has a max of 2 users

#### Scalability

As far as searching existing rooms, this will not scale without some categorization. What happens if you have 1,000 rooms? How will users search all that? So you would want to add subject matter, or tags, to each room. That way you can query `where("tag")==chosenTag`.

Basically each virtual room has fields identifying the 2 users (uid's), AND has subcollections - each collection has a document

uid has fields (accountCreateDate, favoriteColor, AND the uid of each room (as a key) they engage in where the value would be an integer where, for example (1== awaiting response, 2==closed, 3==whatever).

#### Firestore Structure

`users(collection > userUid(document containing aboce said)`

`rooms(collection) roomA(Document w field identifying subject/name) AND sub-collection containing a doc for each pair of participants.`

Comment: hi Ron Royston. thanks for answering. i do not want one user in multiple rooms. i want one user playing in just one room and if he close app then nothing happened but on user2 side(who is still online) there will be a countdown so that user2 wait for user 1 and if he does not reply then app will consider his answer as incorrect.. i hope it makes sense.. and i think firestore is for storing data like images and video etc.. ?

Comment: can you please suggest me any article or youtube video to get help ? or maybe any androidstudio code sample?

Comment: actually i already made signup and signin activities using firebase using email and password, I also already created MCQ app but now i want it like multiplayer thing..

Comment: @RashidIqbal Firebase [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) is for storing media files. [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) is the new database from Firebase (vs the original "Realtime Database"). Firestore has more features. So, create a collections called "quizes" with child documents of quizes. Maybe one named "Types of Wine", another named "Types of Fish". Each quiz document has a subcollection of rooms. That might work?...

Comment: I don't know..Maybe i should search on firestore and learn how to work with firestore

Comment: May i have your facebook or something?

Comment: @RashidIqbal hit me up anytime my info is on my profile.

Comment: I don't see any i for there except your website